# When is it possible to simultaneously parametrize two continuous 2D curves s.t. the y-values are equal at every point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [e, f]$
and $g:[c,d] \rightarrow [e, f]$ be continuous functions s.t. $f(a) = g(c) = e$ and $f(b) = g(d) = f$. What I would like to know is: under what conditions is it possible to find continuous, surjective functions $\phi:[0, 1] \rightarrow [a, b]$
and $\gamma:[0, 1] \rightarrow [c, d]$ such that $f(\phi(x)) = g(\gamma(x))$ for every $x \in [0,1]$.

If $f$ is strictly monotonic then $f^{-1}$ is continuous so we can pick $\phi(x) = f^{-1}(g(\gamma(x)))$
and $\gamma(x) = c - (c - d)x$. I haven't proved it rigorously but I think it's possible to find $\phi$ and $\gamma$ in an analogous way when there are partitions of $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ into a finite number of sub intervals such that $f$ and $g$ are strictly monotonic on each sub interval of their respective domain. This method doesn't work for fractal functions like the Weierstrass function, however.

Is there a simple way of figuring out when $\phi$ and $\gamma$ exist?